# Looking for a neural net visualizer python library for Keras that allows LeakyReLU layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, data-visualization

Like the title says, I have a neural net written with keras/tensorflow and I'd like to make a visualization of my network architecture. I would like a library like [keras-visualizer](https://github.com/lordmahyar/keras-visualizer) or [ann-visualizer](https://github.com/RedaOps/ann-visualizer/issues/5), but they only support specific layer types.

In my case, I'm using LeakyReLU as an activation function, but in Keras this is a layer, and is not one of the ones supported by either of the above libraries. **Are there any easy to use libraries that support LeakyReLU layers in the visualization?**

As a workaround, I could change the activation function just for the visualization, but that makes the visualization is misleading if I'm presenting it.

Comment: what about [netron](https://netron.app/)?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - I like it (and I'll use it in the future) but I'd prefer something that shows nodes like the libraries I linked above.